# How to get a slice of strings using sqlx?

Tags: go, go-gin, sqlx

I am new to glang and I'd like to query Mysql using sqlx to get a slice of strings to be shipped as JSON.
I know how to get the results like this:

```
type MediaURI struct {
    URI string `db:"uri" json:"uri"`
}


func MediaHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var err error
    pid := c.PostForm("pid")
    var medias []MediaURI
    err = shared.Dbmap.Select(&medias, "SELECT uri FROM media WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC ", pid)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"mediaUrls": medias})
}
```

But this gives a slice of structs like this:

> medias are:[{/media/photos/55/abc.png} {/media/photos/55/def.jpg}
>   {/media/photos/55/gdx.png}]

I'm wondering how can I directly get the strings? I've looked at the [docs](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) but the answer (if there) is not clear to me.

Comment: Each record corresponds to one struct in your slice of structs when sqlx do the query.
I think you could construct a slice of string by looping over the slice of struct.

Comment: Just declare `medias` as a slice of strings, if that would work for you?

Comment: @AndyMok I'd like to avoid the extra step.

Comment: @Havelock yes using `var medias []string` gives a slice of strings. Thanks for the tip!